# Отслеживание события в GridPane JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox

Я заполнил GridPane вот таким вот образом:

```
 public void chickBoxItems(){
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> itemsCategory = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Connection con = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
        ResultSet rs;
        String sqlIng = "SELECT category, additional_score FROM consolid";
        try{
            rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlIng);
            while (rs.next()){
                String sqlItemsCategory = rs.getString(1); // достаю из БД названия для CheckBox
                String sqlItemsAdditionalScore = rs.getString(2);
                boolean isExist = items.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.equals(sqlItemsAdditionalScore));
                boolean isExistCategory = itemsCategory.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.equals(sqlItemsCategory)); // Задаю условия что бы checkBox не повторялись
                if (!isExistCategory){ // названия для CheckBox храню в ArrayList
                    itemsCategory.add(sqlItemsCategory);
                }
                if (!isExist){
                    items.add(sqlItemsAdditionalScore);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        gridPane.addColumn(0);
        gridPane.addColumn(1);
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){ // создаю CheckBox из ArrayList
            String elementBox = items.get(i);
            boxAdditionalScore = new CheckBox(elementBox);
            boxAdditionalScore.setId(elementBox);
            gridPane.addRow(i);// добавляю в gridPane строки
            gridPane.add( boxAdditionalScore, 0, i); // добавляю в gridPane CheckBox 
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <itemsCategory.size(); i ++){
            String elementCheckBoxCategory = itemsCategory.get(i);
            boxCategory = new CheckBox(elementCheckBoxCategory);
            boxCategory.setId(elementCheckBoxCategory);
            gridPane.add(boxCategory, 1, i);
        }
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 225, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("GridPane in JavaFX");
        stage.show();
    }
```

Мне нужно что бы после isSelected() происходило действие,
Но я не знаю как вызвать checkBox из gridPane и задать метод isSelected()

Comment: Сразу при создании каждого CheckBox привязывайте слушатель к его свойству isCheckedProperty

Comment: То есть создать EventHandler ... = new EventHandler и привязывать его к CheckBox???

Comment: Точнее не isCheckedProperty, а selectedProperty(). Как-то так: `boxAdditionalScore.selectedProperty().addListener(здесь передаете лямбду или метод-слушатель, который будет обрабатывать изменение состояния);`

Comment: А как можно провернуть другое?? Я подумал и мне нужно вот так вот:
1)Происходит нажатие кнопки
2)С gridPane считываются все отмеченные чекБоксы
3)Отмеченные чекБоксы записываются в поля String
4)Поля передаются в PrepereStatement запрос

Comment: Нужно не "считывать" из gridPane чекбоксы, а добавить их при создании в список, и из списка получать отмеченные.